# Angular DatePipe Output - show UTC instead of GMT

Tags: angular, utc, date-pipe

Is there a way I can use Angular DatePipe to specify a format that shows "UTC" instead of "GMT".
Example Format:

```
{{currentDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a (O)'}}
```

Output: `17/09/2021 10:50:32 AM (GMT-4)`

Is there a way I can get the following output instead:

Output: `17/09/2021 10:50:32 AM (UTC-4)`

i.e. where it says GMT, the output should say UTC instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is purley presentational, and the times of GMT and UTC are always the same, you could create a pipe:

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'utc',
})
export class UtcPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(dateTime: string): string {
    return dateTime.replace('GMT', 'UTC');
  }
}
```

And then the template:

```html
{{ currentDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a (O)' | utc }}
```

[Stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v12-4zxlrm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I've also added the above answer and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
{{ currentDate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a (O)':'UTC' }}
```